# Running Turtlebot with viso2_ros (Linear odometry now working)

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are running stereo_odometer in viso2_ros on the turtlebot. We are running ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

We disabled the /odom publish in turtlebot_node.py, and let stereo_odometer publish to /odom. robot_pose_ekf will now subscribe to the odometry message from viso2_ros.

However, when we visualized it in rviz, the base_link frame only turns but it does not register any linear movements.

We set the "publish_tf" equal to "false", because robot_pose_ekf (not stereo_odometer) is supposed to compute the tf based on the odometry information from viso2_ros.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this?

Since the angular odometry is performing fine, we think the visual odometry is up and running well... but we're not sure how to debug a potential issue with transforms (tf) or publishing/subscribing

(we did write a custom tf between the base_link and our pair of stereo cameras, that seems to be correct by looking at rviz)

New info:
We found out that the problem is in the library of libviso2. When the robot is stationary, the process method of VisionOdometryStereo returns true, but when the robot starts to move, it returns false.
Will bad camera calibration or bad camera placement (we used 2 identical USB cameras placed side by side) cause the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39068/running-turtlebot-with-viso2_ros-(linear-odometry-now-working)/) by [YumiLench](https://answers.ros.org/users/2866/yumilench/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the code, it appears that false is returned when the number of valid feature matches between the left and right stereo frames is lower than 6 (see [here](http://ros.org/doc/api/libviso2/html/viso__stereo_8cpp_source.html#l00040)). Have you calibrated your camera properly and do you use rectified images as input for viso2? Also, are camera images somehow synchronized and not too blurry? I imagine the combination of bad synchronization and rolling shutter could be problematic.

Testing viso2 with a custom stereo system (with synced frames and calibrated using [StereoCalibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration)) showed promising results for us (including linear/translational motion).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First make sure your stereo camera system is working correctly. When you are able to generate good looking disparity maps and/or point clouds (e.g. by following the [tutorial on choosing good stereo parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters)) the `stereo_odometer` of viso2_ros should work fine. viso2_ros does not use the disparity map nor the point cloud that come from `stereo_image_proc` but if they look good your stereo system is working.

To debug your tf tree, try the following: do not publish any tf and run just the `stereo_odometer` with the parameter `base_link_frame_id` set to the frame_id of your stereo system. Visualize the transform `/odom -> <frame_id of your camera>` in rviz by setting the fixed frame to `/odom`. Does the frame move when the camera moves? If not, `stereo_odometer` is not working for some reason (too few features, inconsistent matches). You might try to adjust the parameter `match_disp_tolerance`.

If the tf `/odom -> <frame_id of your camera>` looks good there must be some other problem in your tf tree.

A side-note: I just moved the former srv_vision stack that contained viso2_ros to a new stack called [viso2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2), please update your repository.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1